# Good Alfresco Tutorials?

Tags: alfresco, content-management-system

I'm developing a PHP application that connects to an Alfresco instance for application content storage. Never having used Alfresco before, I'm looking for some good tutorials that explain the structure and organization of an Alfresco repository, i.e. how Nodes work, etc.

I haven't found much beyond the Alfresco Docs on the alfresco.com website, and while they do a good job explaining how to setup and configure an alfresco solution, they don't seem to talk as much about how the content repository is structured. A google search doesn't reveal much in the way of free online tutorials for Alfresco development.

Anyone know any good free tutorials for this, or will I have to end up finding a book written on the subject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thay aren't that many good resources on the web.

But you can check out Alfresco blogs: http://www.alfresco.com/blogs/

Alfresco wiki is a good source: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Main_Page

And this book (may be the best book for starting with Alfresco): http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Alfresco-Practical-Solutions-for-Enterprise-Content-Management.productCd-0470571047.html

Have fun with Alfresco! :)

Comment: Thanks! That wiki looks like it's got some good resources, and the book looks like it would be very useful. Maybe I'll just have to pony up the money for it. :)

Answer (score 11):

I'll humbly submit the set of [Alfresco tutorials](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series) that I have written on my blog, ecmarchitect.com. They cover things like custom content models, custom actions, web scripts, behaviors, and workflows.

If you are using Alfresco 4, read the "2nd Edition" of the tutorials, where available. Those cover the most recent stuff.

Also, as you are developing a PHP app, you will be interested in the CMIS section of the "Custom Content Types" tutorial. Learn CMIS, then go grab the [PHP API](http://chemistry.apache.org/php/phpclient.html) from the Apache Chemistry project. You can then use that to remotely perform CRUD functions against the repo from your PHP app.